# Heroku SocketError on POST submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, internal-server-error

When submitting a form to create a simple object, I'm getting a SocketError:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 526ms
SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:58:in `block in create'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:57:in `create'
```

I've Google'd and searched through StackOverflow, everyone else with similar errors seems to be sending email. I'm not -- this is just a form to create a simple blog post that belongs to a user.

This app IS using SendGrid (though this particular functionality does not use it), however, even after removing SendGrid, the SocketError persists.

Here's the code from the controller, referenced in the error message:

```
  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_posts_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Additionally, other posts mentioning this error seem to have issues with host declarations/URL's/URI's and weird configurations in production environment files. I don't seem to have these problems, and I can't seem to determine if this is a problem with my application or a host configuration issue with Heroku. I'm inclined to believe it's a mistake on my end.

I've been cranking on this for a while now, with no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is a mail being delivered on post#save?
ActionMailer should be configured to use sendgrid manually on the Cedar stack:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#actionmailer